# Converting lists into values using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, list

Here is the code that I have.  I run this code and it gives me the following error:  "TypeError:  value#1-unsupported type: list".  I am having a hard time getting it to be formatted so I am attaching a snapshot of what my code looks like in PythonWin when it is formatted[image].  I am posting another image of what my error message actually looks like.  What is interesting is that it actually prints out the first row of my csv.[image]

Comment: What I think anyone is going to need in order to help you would be more specific information.  You have your entire program and the error code, but we don't know at what point it is generating this error.  You could even try something as simple as adding a line of print "here 1", print "here 2", etc... after each section just during this trouble shooting, that way you can see what steps it has completed successfully and identify what step it is trying to accomplish next when the error is generated.

Comment: Please don't post code and errors as images. Use the `{}`button to format as code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prints reveal arrays of size 1 - but still an array!

```
a = [['a'],['b']]
print a[0]
# ['a']
print a[0][0]
# a
```

So try updating each subset in your code from

```
FIPCODE = fipslist[x]
```

to

```
FIPCODE = fipslist[x][0]
```

Comment: Thanks!  That solved the problem in the attribute table but now only one point is showing up, when it used to show all of the points in the shapefile.  All of the points are listed in the attribute table but only one shows up when you add it to the map.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I got the problem solved and got all of the points to show up as well as the data.  Is the [0] a placemarker in the subset?

Comment: @ebee32 the 0 means the 1st element of the array, as it is of size 1 it is the value you are looking for